# VIM: "langmap" breaks insert mode mappings

Tags: vim

I have this in my .vimrc:

```
set langmap=\\;l,lk,kj,jh
inoremap jk <ESC>
```

The mapping doesn't work, anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Since `k` is being translated to `j`, press `jj` instead?

Comment: langmapped keys are not checked for mappings. This is an open issue with vim.

Comment: The idea was to hit the actual jk keys and have it exit insert mode. Pressing jj doesn't work though.